# Unable to make API calls | Jetty, Maven, REST on VSCode

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty

I'm new to Java WebServices and Maven. I want to launch an application so I can call http:/localhost:8080/`resourcePath` through my browser.

My Jetty server is running but it returns a 404 no matter the path I give. I suspect it doesn't recognize the application at all. Maybe it has the wrong path.

**Here's my application** (path /Users/orelregev/my-project/src/main/java/com/example/MyApplication.java):

```
// all required imports
@ApplicationPath("/webapi")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("resources");
    }
}
```

**Here's my resource** (path /Users/orelregev/my-project/src/main/java/resources/Hello.Java):

```
// all required imports
`@Path("/welcome")
public class Hello {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello world";
    }`
```

**I run the project by this command:**

```
/Users/orelregev/Downloads/apache-maven-3.9.6/bin/mvn org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:run
```

I use:

- Maven: version 3.9.6 (saved in `Users/orelregev/Downloads`); `pom.xml` has dependencies for Jersey and Jetty
- Jetty Plugin: version 6.1.10
- IDE: VSCode

Would appreciate any input on the potential problem(s) and solution. Thank you! :)

I've tried (and still failed to make API calls):

- Moving the resource `Hello.java` into `com.example` (the application package)
- Different versions of Jetty and Jersey in `pom.xml`
- Changing the application to Application rather than sub-class ResourceConfig
- Change the @ApplicationPath and @Path to simpler things

Comment: The use of `org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:run` means you are using a version of Jetty that has long ago been declared End of Life.  The last version of Jetty using that plugin was Jetty 6.x which was EOL back in 2010.